# How do I use an entity reference field as a sidebar navigation on a view?

Tags: views, nodes

I have 2 content types: *category* and *project*. On *project*, I have a reference field to *category*.

I would like to list all my nodes from *project* in a view and then use all the *category* nodes as links for filtering this list.

I know it is possible with a taxonomy term, but I'm trying to achieve it with a reference field. Is it possible with the view UI?

I'm using Drupal 8.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Doing this with content types is really no different than with taxonomies. You can leverage the reference value with a Views relationship.
You description sounds like it would use two Views, one for the block of navigational links in the sidebar, and the other for the lists of projects.

For the first you just want a view of the categories. I'd use fields and rewrite the output to link to each category title to a url like `/projects/{{category_title}}`. "Rewrite output" is an option available in the modal for the field. Alternatively, and perhaps more straightforward is to use the option to "output as a link."

The second page display View is based on the project type, and has a relationship to the category. Create a contextual filter to pull the category title from the URL, matching whatever you set up in the block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With that option, I can't use ajax then? Also, can you please tell me how to rewrite the output? 

I found this module who works for me at the moment : https://www.drupal.org/project/verf

Comment: Nothin in the original post indicates a need for Ajax. Maybe you have a second question. I added information about field rewrites in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I forgot to mention the need for Ajax, but it's not a problem right now. What I don't understand is the fact that the url on my category's link bring me to the node of the category and so I leave the view... Also, what do you think of the verf module?

Comment: "... the url on my category's link bring me to the node of the category ..." <- That's why you want to choose one of the rewrite options for the field in the modal for that field. In fact, you can choose "output as a link" and set it to the url you want.

Comment: I think I miss something here... Whatever I wrote in the "link path" input on the "revrite results" accordion from the "configure field: Content:Title" modal, the link in my view box try to bring me to a page, 404 or true link...

Comment: I can't help that without knowing what you set the link path to and what path you created for the project page view. Add that information to the post.

Comment: I succeeded with your method, thank you! Did I need to create a content-type category "all" for my page project then?

Comment: Only if that's an option.